# Issue with OutputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to display an image, which created dynamical using GDI+ 
this is my code

```
    Font font = new Font("Impact", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(300,50);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    g.DrawString("This is a test", font, Brushes.Blue,10,5);
    image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    g.Dispose();
    image.Dispose();
```

The problem is when I am using FireFox the output is like this:

[image]

But in IE it showing correctly(Didn't test in any other browser). What was the mistake.?

Comment: Show use the code in your default.aspx.cs page

Comment: Its just on Page_Load event

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are setting the [`Response.ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx).

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
```

Found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1572453.aspx/1